# Updating a table with react.js results in the wrong row order

Tags: reactjs

I have a table that has a number of generated rows (from a props value), and then a static row at the bottom, when i do an update that changes the props value to add another value, my static final row is no longer the final row in the browser, its like the DOM differ thinks my static row is from the collection (i tried adding a `key={"foo"}` to the static row but that didn't help).

Here's a example of what happens, when you click add the resulting table is 1,2,3,add,4 rather than 1,2,3,4,add.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
     <script type="text/jsx">
        
        var Table = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            var r = this.props.values.map(function(v) {
              return (<tr key={v}><td>{v}</td></tr>);
            });
            return (
                  <table>
                      {r}
                      <tr><td>Last Row</td></tr>
                  </table>
            );
          }
        });
        
        var TableContainer = React.createClass({
          getInitialState: function() {
            return { values: ["1","2","3"]} 
          },
          addValue: function() {
            this.setState({values: ["1","2","3","4"]});
          },
          render: function() {
            return (
              <div>
                <Table values={this.state.values} />
                <button onClick={this.addValue}>add</button>
              </div>
            );
          }
        });
        
     React.render(
          <TableContainer  />,
          document.getElementById("content")
        );
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are rendering `<table>` using React you have to remember about adding `<tbody>` (and if necessary `<thead>`). All browsers add them to their DOM node automatically but this makes confusion inside React Virtual DOM.

All you need to change is:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var r = this.props.values.map(function(v) {
            return (<tr key={v}><td>{v}</td></tr>);
        });
        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {r}
                <tr><td>Last Row</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```